# memoir Template for APA style

Tags: memoir, indentation, page-numbering, apa-style

I typically use Chicago style, but a student of mine is interested in doing APA (which I know only peripherally). I've created a template using `memoir` class, which *almost* does what is required. Not being an expert at tinkering with the guts of `memoir` or at APA, I'm interested in

1. running head and page number on *all* pages
2. automatically indenting all paragraphs (SOLVED)
3. ensuring that my style overrides have been done canonically, i.e., in the right way, consistent with `memoir` principles
4. similarly, elimination of 'Chapter N' in page note headers done canonically

I've annotated the example but can list issues here if that would be preferable. A few things here are not altogether 'minimal' but showcase where this is going.

```
\documentclass[oneside,article]{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{none}% remove numbering of chapters/sections
\aliaspagestyle{title}{empty}% suppress page number on title page
\pagestyle{headings}
\headstyles{default}
% The following section attempts to implement the requirements for
% APA 7 at https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/paper-format/headings
\chapterstyle{article}
    % Centre level 1 header instead of left justify
    \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\centering\chaptitlefont #1}
% The \section style (Level 2) seems fine as it is.
\setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\itshape\memRTLraggedright}% Level 3
\setparaheadstyle{\indent\normalsize\bfseries}% Level 4
\setsubparaheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\itshape}% Level 5

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec,libertinus}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
    \SetLanguageKeys{english}{indentfirst=true}
\usepackage[style=apa,annotation,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\title{APA memoir template} 
\author{A.\,U.\ Thor}

\makepagenote
% Get rid of 'Chapter N' in endnote headers.
% Don't think I need the commented out bits, but shows how I got there
% using borrowed code.
\renewcommand{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{%
%  \ifnum#2=0
    \section*{#3}%
%  \else
%    \section*{#1 #2 #3}%
%  \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\vskip\baselineskip
\begin{center}
Course info
\end{center}
\clearpage
\end{titlingpage}

\mainmatter
\begin{abstract}
Abstract text goes here.
\end{abstract}

\chapter{Level One Heading}
\lipsum[2][1-3]\pagenote{Example of a page note in the first \enquote{chapter}.}

\section{Level Two Heading}
Level two text goes here.

\subsection{Level Three Heading}
Level three text goes here.

\paragraph{Level Four Heading.} Level four text follows behind it; would be nice if the fullstop/period
were autoinserted in correct formatting.

\subparagraph{Level Five Heading.} Level five text; ditto.

\printbibliography
\printpagenotes

\chapter{Tables}
Tables go here.

\chapter{Figures}
Figures go here.

\appendix
\chapter{Sample Appendix}
Appendix text goes here.

\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not so sure what are you aiming (my knowledge of APA is less than peripheral). Since you are using `polyglossia`, you can get rid of `\apaindent` if yod add `\PolyglossiaSetup{english}{indentfirst=true}` to your preamble. Then you can adjust the indentation with `\setlength{\parindent}{...}`. For me it would be better if you list the issues in your code.

Comment: Another observation, the title page does not look centered. Is this intended or do you think it would be better to use a different geometry for that page?

Comment: @LuisTurcio Both items noted, thanks. Will edit tomorrow.

Comment: @LuisTurcio Added `\SetLanguageKeys` rather than `\PolyglossiaSetup` to avoid error message, added `oneside` class option to fix centring of title page. Updated and clarified request list.

Comment: There is an `apa` document class that might have done most things for you. https://texdoc.net/pkg/apa This may be simpler than redesigning everything with `memoir`

Comment: @AlanMunn I will have a look at that. (The attraction with `memoir`, though, is that it has everything one could imagine built in and compatible, hence the attempt.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Hmm. APA5. In that regard, likely `apa6` and `apa7` are to be preferred, probably (again, I'm not the intended end-user); for me it's a worthwhile exercise in 'how would one...' which also puts me in a better position to support students locally.

Comment: I've never understood the whole APA fetish, especially for students. The APA guidelines for formatting documents are meant for submitting to APA journals, and they're pretty idiosyncratic. I understand the need for APA bibliography formatting, but for student work requiring formatting like an APA journal seems totally unnecessary.

Comment: @AlanMunn I completely agree, especially as it's totally typographically idiosyncratic, to my mind. Unfortunately, we have some faculty who insist on foisting the (changing) professional standard on the student and downgrade otherwise. Clearly they should be sacked, but unfortunately they are not employed by the Monty Python gang!

Comment: Yes, my soapbox when training my TAs is that teaching is not about power. And this kind of enforcement on the part of some faculty is *all* about power.